# Has ParseCrashReporting been deprecated for Android SDK ?

Tags: android, parse-platform, sdk

I know that I can use the parse sdk using
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.3'

But how do I use Parse Crash Reporting and I can't even find it.

Comment: I have been looking for same from last one one.

Comment: @user1154390 I hope someone answers this. This is really bugging me

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: @user1154390 Hey, check this out : https://parse.com/downloads/android/Parse/latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has not been deprecated. However it seems it was [not added](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/184) in the initial release.

If you download the Zip from there homepage it is now included. 
[Here is a direct link.](https://parse.com/downloads/android/Parse/latest)